# Команда fuser

Tags: bash

Команда `fuser -mk /eop` должна завершать все процессы, которые используют файлы на `/eop`.
Однако, если после этого выполнить команду `lsof /eop` (или аналогичную) получается, что процессы, использующие `/eop` не завершились. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Или прав для kill (сигнал) (в смысле uid пользователя процесса / uid автора fuser) не хватает или процессы, которые не завершились перехватывают SIGTERM.

Можно попробовать fuser -ki -9 -m /eop

fuser будет требовать подтверждения на удаление процесса